# Is there tool similar to CXF wsdl2java can generate client code for aegis?

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java, aegis

CXF wsdl2java tool can generate client code which databinding is jaxb. It seems wsdl2java can not generate aegis code. Is there a similar tool can generate client code for aegis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Aegis is designed as a purely "java first" databinding as it cannot handle a lot of various schema concepts and such.   If starting from WSDL, JAXB is strongly encouraged.